# Collapse 3 columns on mobile device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap layout like so:

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 top-col-left">
          <h4>24 Hour High</h4>
          <h1>$7.88</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 top-col-center">
          <h4>24 Hour Low</h4>
          <h1>$1.88</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 top-col-right">
          <h4>24 Hour Change</h4>
          <h1>$2.88</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When viewed on a mobile device the layout will become 3 rows of one column. Is it possible to display this as 1 row of 2 columns and 1 row of 1 column instead?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will become 2 rows with 2 and 1 columns respectively on `xs` (<768px) devices

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 top-col-left">
      <h4>24 Hour High</h4>
      <h1>$7.88</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 top-col-center">
      <h4>24 Hour Low</h4>
      <h1>$1.88</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 top-col-right">
      <h4>24 Hour Change</h4>
      <h1>$2.88</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is build around a 12 column grid system, currently your html/css is saying that each column should take up a third of the screen.

If you are wanting to have 2 columns and then wrapped underneath a single column then something like this would work,

```
<div class="col-sm-6"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6"></div>
<div class="col-sm-12"></div>
```

You can add other classes for larger screens sizes.